# How to move an element in an array to the last element?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to know how to move an element in an array to the last position.

```
Dim lastElement As String = strChar(UBound(strChar)) 'J.


    For i As Integer = 0 To characters.Count - 1
        If characters(i).actor = searchName And characters(i).title = searchMovie Then
            For j = UBound(strChar) To LBound(strChar) + strChar.Count - 1 Step -1
                strChar(j) = strChar(j - 1)
            Next
        End If
    Next



    strChar(LBound(strChar)) = lastElement
```

So here I have a structure characters and an array strChar.

I looked this code up on the internet and can't figure it out. It won't move the position of the element to the last or the first, but copies an element to the top.

I'm supposed to be deleting an element, but first I have to move the element before redim preserving it.

I wish I could use an arraylist, but i can't because i'm not supposed to for school.

Comment: You should post the whole code ...

Comment: `ArrayList` is outdated.  Given the choice, a `List(Of T)` would be better.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

A trick to this is that when you're re-arranging elements in an array, you have to save an entry somewhere outside the array, or you're going to overwrite one.

If it's legal to simply swap this element with what is currently the last element, then:

```
dim temp = characters(i)
characters(i) = characters(characters.length-1)
characters(characters.length-1) = temp
```

If you have to preserve the relative order:

```
dim temp = characters(i)
for j = i to characters.length-2
  characters(j)=characters(j+1)
next
characters(characters.length-1) = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the best way to do this is to copy last item in the array to the position of the item i'm trying to delete, then redim preserve the array so the bottom item is deleted. essentially, i'm making a copy of an element to the position i'm trying to delete, and getting rid of that bottom element.

```
    Dim searchName As String = txtActorName.Text
    Dim searchMovie As String = txtMovieTitle.Text

    For i As Integer = 0 To characters.Count - 1
        If searchName = characters(i).actor And searchMovie = characters(i).title Then
            characters(i) = characters(characters.Count - 1)
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve characters(characters.Count - 2)
```

i'm using a structure array as you can see here.